# SQL query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I've tried replacing the variables with something that can be found in the database and the query seems to work fine. Also tried echoing the $tour_type variable and it gets the parameter from the url. This is the code:

```
if (isset ($_GET['tour_type']))
{
    $tour_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['tour_type']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tour WHERE tour_type_1='$tour_type' OR tour_type_2='$tour_type' OR tour_type_3='$tour_type' OR tour_type_4='$tour_type' OR tour_type_5='$tour_type' AND type='buc'";
}
else
{
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM tour WHERE type='buc'";
}
```

The problem is when the page has a `tour_type` parameter set up. When it doesn't it takes the query from the "else" and it works fine.

I can't get it to display a error so I can debug it (some JavaScript doesn't let the page load while there's an error) so it must be debugged without relying on the error message from MySQL. I guess it has something to do with the way I added the conditions after the `WHERE` but can't figure it out what I did wrong.

Comment: Is this *all* of your code?

Comment: BTW: welcome to the world of [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)...

Comment: That is the problematic part of the code. Changing that caused the error. I really don't think it would help if I'd post more.

Comment: I'd like to try the tour `'; drop table tour; --`.

Comment: ignoring all the other problems people have pointed out, you can GREATLY simplify things with `WHERE '$tour_type' IN (tour_type1, tour_type_2, ....)`, or just normalize things properly from the get-go.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() is not that hard to add after I fix my problem, is it?

Comment: I **HIGHLY** recommend you don't build your queries with string concatenation.  Create a parameterized query and pass the parameters in.  That will prevent a lot of headaches for you later, related to SQL injection.

Comment: Updated for the h8rz (not the ones with actually useful information in their comments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing `AND` and `OR` clauses without `()` to enforce the evaluation order, so your query, as written, is being executed as

```
... WHERE A or B or C or (D and E)
```

when you really want it to be

```
... WHERE (A or B or C or D) AND (E)
```

and as others have pointed out, you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy getting your server pwn3d.

A better (still injection vulnerable) structure would be:

```
... WHERE '$tour_type' IN (tour_type1, tour_type2, ...) AND type='$buc';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the answer I needed! :)

Comment: You should read the code again. Added the mysqli_real_escape_string(). :)

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM tour WHERE '$tour_type' IN (tour_type_1, tour_type_2, tour_type_3, tour_type_4, tour_type_5) AND type='buc'";` still has the same problem... :( page won't load

Answer (score 1):

There is **no error** in your code posted above.      Make sure.

1. Sending data **method** is `get` or `post`

   ```
   <form action='' method='post/get'....>
   ```
2. Html field **name** is assigned with `tour_type`

   ```
   <input type='text' name='tour_type'...>
   ```

Comment: It's actually a simple `<a href="http://www.example.com/all_tours_grid.php?tour_type=city_sightseeing">`.

Comment: no immediate error, but there was a logic error due to bad operator precedence.